# SQL Query to parse numbers from name

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting

The DBMS in this case is SQL Server 2012.

I need a SQL query that will grab just the numbers from a device name. I've got devices that follow a naming scheme that SHOULD look like this:

```
XXXnnnnn
```

or

```
XXXnnnnn-XX
```

Where X is a letter and n is a number which should be left padded with 0's where appropriate.  However, not all of the names are properly padded in this way.

So, imagine you have a column that looks something like this:

```
    Name
    ----
    XXX01234
    XXX222
    XXX0390-A2
    XXX00965-A1
```

I need an SQL query that will return results from this example column as follows.

```
    Number
    ------
    01234
    00222
    00390
    00965
```

Anyone have any thoughts? I've tried things like casting the name first as a float and then as an int, but to be honest, I'm just not skilled enough with SQL yet to find the solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the used DBMS ?

Comment: Sorry, I really should have included that in the post, shouldn't I?  It's MSSQL.  I'll edit the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server does not have great string parsing functions.  For your particular example, I think a `case` statement might be the simplest approach:

```
select (case when number like '___[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
             then substring(number, 4, 5)
             when number like '___[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
             then '0' + substring(number, 4, 4)
             when number like '___[0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
             then '00' + substring(number, 4)
             when number like '___[0-9][0-9]%'
             then '000' + substring(number, 4, 2)
             when number like '___[0-9][0-9]%'
             then '0000' + substring(number, 4, 1)
             else '00000'
        end) as EmbeddedNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

If the first 3 chars are always needed to be removed, then you can do something like that (will work if the characters will start only after '-' sign):

```
DECLARE @a AS TABLE ( a VARCHAR(100) );

INSERT  INTO @a
VALUES
        ( 'XXX01234' ),
        ( 'XXX222' ),
        ( 'XXX0390-A2' ),
        ( 'XXX00965-A1' );

SELECT RIGHT('00000' + SUBSTRING(a, 4, CHARINDEX('-',a+'-')-4),5)
FROM  @a
-- OUTPUT
01234
00222
00390
00965
```

Another option (will extract numbers after first 3 characters):

```
SELECT
    RIGHT('00000' + LEFT(REPLACE(a, LEFT(a, 3), ''),
                         COALESCE(NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%',
                                                  REPLACE(a, LEFT(a, 3), '')),
                                         0) - 1,
                                  LEN(REPLACE(a, LEFT(a, 3), '')))), 5)
FROM
    @a;

    -- OUTPUT
    01234
    00222
    00390
    00965
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work even when XXX can be of different len:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE ( n NVARCHAR(50) )

INSERT  INTO @t
VALUES  ( 'XXXXXXX01234' ),
        ( 'XX222' ),
        ( 'X0390-A2' ),
        ( 'XXXXXXX00965-A1' )

SELECT  REPLICATE('0', 5 - LEN(n)) + n AS n
FROM    ( SELECT    SUBSTRING(n, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', n),
                              CHARINDEX('-', n + '-') - PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', n)) AS n
          FROM      @t
        ) t
```

Output:

```
n
01234
00222
00390
00965
```

Comment: Author mentioned that he has XXXnnnnn or XXXnnnnn-XX

Answer (score 0):

This might work :

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000'
             + SUBSTRING(Col, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF((PATINDEX('%-%', Col)), 0) - 1, LEN(Col))), 5)
FROM   (SELECT REPLACE(YourColumn, 'XXX', '') Col
        FROM   YourTable)t
```

[SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cbd2e/1)